Cloud SQL issue after PHP update to 8.2
I am using PDO connection for Cloud SQL from website. I have updated PHP to 8.2 recently and connection has stopped working and giving error

[MY-010914] [Server] Bad handshake

even though there is no change is connection code. I have regenerated certificates on SQL as we are only allowing client certificate and SSL encryption connection, still doesn't work.
Here is the PHP code:
$this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database",
    self::USERNAME,
    self::PASSWORD, 
    [
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY                => $ck,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT               => $cc,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA                 => $sc,                    
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
]);

Has anyone faced similar issue? or can help to resolve this?

"I have updated PHP to 8.2" from which old version ? (Because this seems related to SSL (or secure communications), and that ....(has changed since PHP 4.0 )

Please share MySQL with us too (see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/241665/162995 ) (BTW: was MySQL updated too ???)
